# map/set iterators incompatible - checking if key exists in map

Tags: c++, dictionary

When function is executing, I have the following error: **map/set iterators incompatible**.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
bool isAuto(string table_name, string field_name, SCHEMA schema)
{
    if (schema[table_name][field_name].find("max") == schema[table_name]["field_name"].end())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return schema[table_name][field_name]["auto"] == "true" && schema[table_name][field_name]["type"] == "int";
}
```

Data:

```
SCHEMA schema;
        schema["przedmioty"]["id"]["type"] = "int";
        schema["przedmioty"]["id"]["auto"] = "true";
        schema["przedmioty"]["nazwa"]["type"] = "string";
        schema["przedmioty"]["semestr"]["type"] = "int";
        schema["przedmioty"]["semestr"]["max"] = "10";
        schema["przedmioty"]["semestr"]["min"] = "1";
```

Type definition:

```
typedef map<string, map<string, map<string, string> > > SCHEMA;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
schema[table_name][field_name].find("max") == 
    schema[table_name]["field_name"].end()
```

Your second `field_name` is in quotations, so it's comparing iterators from two different maps (unless `field_name` has the value "field_name"), which isn't valid.